# Linux - same function called when loading so dynamically and statically

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, shared-libraries, dlopen

I have a c++ project which compiles to a .so file (compiling using g++5).
In another project (under the same solution) I have a test which links to this project (CMake's command target_link_libraries(...)).

I compile the project, and copy the output .so file to lets say "/tmp/proj.so".

In addition to linking the test to the project, I also use `dlopen` to dynamically load "/tmp/proj.so", which has a global function `create_foo` which creates a new `foo` object.

The goals I'm trying to achieve is to have a test which compares two versions of the same project one against the other so that I know I'm not breaking anything by changing stuff in the project.

After opening with `dlopen` I call `dlsym` to find `create_foo`, and then invoke it.
`create_foo is` something like:

```
extern "C" bool create_foo(foo** instance){
    *instance = new foo();
    return true;
}
```

So in my test I have something like (I removed unrelated code like null checks):

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include "foo.h"

int main()
{
    foo f1;
    void* handle = dlopen("/tmp/proj.so", RTLD_NOW);
    bool(*create_foo_func)(foo**);
    create_foo_func = (bool(*)(foo**))dlsym(handle, "create_foo");

    foo* f2;
    (*create_foo_func)(&f2);

    assert(f1.bar() == 10);
    assert(f2->bar() == 10);
}
```

Both assertions are ok. 
So next thing I did was to change `foo::bar` to `return 5` instead of `10`, compiled the project **but I did not change the /tmp/proj.so file!**
And when I ran the program, I got:

```
f1.bar() == 5
f2->bar() == 5 //I would expect this to be 10 since I did not change it
```

So I get `5` in both calls, as opposed to what I was hoping which is `f1.bar()==5` and `f2->bar() == 10`.

I know for sure that the dll is loading and the `create_foo` in the dynamic so is called (I can see it in the module list of the debugger, and also if I try to dlsym("NOT_create_foo") it will fail, and also the other way fails i.e changing `create_foo` function name to something but not changing /tmp/proj.so).

When I added a printf("static linkage") in the code, compiled it and left the /tmp/proj.so" file unchanged (meaning it does not have this printf) I see that this is printed twice.

So what am I doing wrong here?

The real project I'm working on is big and is using CMake. I might have left out important details which I did not think are relevant, if you think I should look somewhere please comment and I will edit with the answer.

Comment: Is the `foo::bar` function is defined inline in the `foo` class? Or do your application link with the (modified) source file containing the `foo::bar` definition?

Comment: @Some programmer dude, the foo::bar is not inline. It compiles with the definition. Also note that the issue start with the constructor. I.e when I print in the ctor both f1 and f2 print,despite the fact that I did not copy the modified .so

Comment: To clarify. The implementation of the `foo` class is in  your program, not the library. So whatever changes you make to it will be inside your program. All the library really does is create an instance, the functions for that instance are already in your program.

Comment: I'm used to Visual Studio's terminology (but now I'm working with CMake in linux), so in Visual Studio terms I have a project that compiles to a dynamic library (.so file) which consists of several headers and source files. The main object in this lib is Foo, so the header and implementation of Foo is in this project. In another project (different folder with another Cmake) I have a test that references this project (CMake's "add_dependencies" and "target_link_libraries"), In this test I have the `main` function from the question. (cont' in next comment)

Comment: So what I was hoping is that if I change the implementation of Foo, e.g Foo::Foo() will now print "I'm not in the .so file", then by creating `Foo f1;` this will be printed out, but when I create f2 with `(*create_foo_func)(&f2);` it will not print this line. Unfortunatly both f1 and f2 print the line meaning they both create the same type of object (or at least use the same implementation)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you want be able to achieve what you want. As far as compiler is concerned, objects have the same type so it'll generate call to same implementation. At link time it will be resolved `foo::bar` defined in executable.

```
      $ g++ main.cc -c
      $ objdump -rd
      ...
      44:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  49 <main+0x49>
      45: R_X86_64_PC32       _ZN3foo3barEv-0x4
      ...
      6e:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  73 <main+0x73>
      6f: R_X86_64_PC32       _ZN3foo3barEv-0x4
```

Comment: First, thanks.
Seconds, Do you know why this is the case?
Third, Is there a workaround for this case? Ithought about renaming but wasn't sure if it'll work

Comment: "Do you know why this is the case" - well, that's just how it works - for compiler both objects have identical type so it'll generate assembly code to call the same local method.

Comment: "Third, Is there a workaround for this case?" - you could rename reference implementation of foo (e.g. foo_ref). In that case you'll inform compiler to distinguish two objects.

Answer (score 0):

The dlopen man page does not say so, but [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlopen.html), it says

```
Only a single copy of an object file is brought into the address space, even if dlopen() is invoked multiple times in reference to the file, and even if different pathnames are used to reference the file.
```

and the linux dlopen manpage:

```
   If the same library is loaded again with dlopen(), the same file handle is returned. 
   The dl library maintains reference counts for library handles, so a dynamic library 
   is not deallocated until dlclose() has been called on it as many times as dlopen() 
   has succeeded on it.
```

So it seems that dlopen treats `/tmp/proj.so` as the same library as the one already loaded for the test executable itself. You should be able to test that by comparing returned handles.

Comment: This is not the case I described. I am not dynamically opening the same library, Only once, the second is done in linkage by the linker (after compilation)

Comment: It's the same: when you run a dynamically linked binary, the shared libraries needed are loaded with the same mechanism for you. This is done by the /lib/ld-linux.so program.